# Adding style to select options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to change the styling of HTML select options such as color and background.  It doesn't work for  margin: 20px, border. Been trying different things and with JS and jQuery.

```css
.unifaun-checkout-option-agents option {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="unifaun-checkout-option-agents-wrapper">
  <select class="unifaun-checkout-option-agents">
    <option value="SE-837500">ICA NÄRA VALLBY,VALLBY CENTRUM,VÄSTERÅS</option>
    <option value="SE-748700">ICA NÄRA PETTERSBERG,JAKOBSGATAN 45,VÄSTERÅS</option>
    <option value="SE-650600">AMS SUPERMARKET,SLÄGGKASTARGATAN 1,VÄSTERÅS</option>
    <option value="SE-605600">TUNBYKIOSKEN,TUNBYTORPSGATAN 2A,VÄSTERÅS</option>
    <option value="SE-803900">MATÖPPET AROSLUNDS LIVS,AROSVÄGEN 32,VÄSTERÅS</option>
    <option value="SE-635900">CITYGROSS VÄSTERÅS,KRANKROKSGATAN 21,VÄSTERÅS</option>
    <option value="SE-966900">GRYTA KIOSKEN VÄSTERÅS,HERMELINVÄGEN 2,VÄSTERÅS</option>
    <option value="SE-701600">RÅBY TOBAK &amp; SPEL,RÅBY CENTRUM,VÄSTERÅS</option>
    <option value="SE-706800">TEMPO SKALLBERGET,EMAUSGATAN 35,VÄSTERÅS</option>
    <option value="SE-629900">DIREKTEN SKULTUNA,VÄSTERÅSVÄGEN 26,SKULTUNA</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Comment: For any particular OS or browsers?

Answer (score -1):

Try this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp) link.
If stylings are not working for classes, try using "id" to make changes.